# State Change in one class when the buttons are clicked on left hand sidebar in the UI and data shown in the content area on right hand side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- There are two classes one is caregiver and other is Registeration Form.
- I want to show the registeration form class inside the content tag of caregiver when the regitser button available on the sidebars is clicked. So different data needs to be shown with each button clicked on right side

```
          class Caregiver extends React.Component {
    
      state = {
        collapsed: false,
      };
    
      toggle = () => {
        this.setState({
          collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
    
          <Layout>
    
            <Sider
              trigger={null}
              collapsible
              collapsed={this.state.collapsed}
              style={{ background:'#122a44'}}
            >
              
            </Sider>
            
          </Layout>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default Caregiver;


    class RegisterationForm extends React.Component {
    
      handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
          if (!err) {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          }
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    
        return (
       
          <div>
                  <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="registeration-abs">
      
                  </Form>
          </div>
    
        );
      }
    }
    
    const RegisterPatients = Form.create()(RegisterationForm);
    
    export default  RegisterPatients;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add  in the content tag.
And add a state of showingForm, triggered by the button you add (simialr to your sidebar triggering) :

```html
<Content>
  <RegisterationForm showing={this.state.showingForm} />
</Content>
```

Inside, RegisterationForm render function can be defined as conditionally showing the content :

```js
render() {
  return (
    !this.props.showing ? null : 
      ....
  );
}
```